# Appointment class

Tags: java, date, object

I'm trying to create a method that would add an appointment to an arraylist appointmentCalndar. This method would validate the date to see if the user input is equal to the SimpleDateFormat in my code, the startTime and the endTime of the appointment and to see if its in the future or not.

I have tried using the java Date api to check this but when I try to extend the class to get access to the attributes it always causes an error on compile time. So overall my question is what would the best way to compare an object of appointment type to an object of type date? I try using accesors to getDate() and startTime and endTime but it won't allow me to get them also.

```
public AppointmentDate(String appString)
{
    // 1) split ithe string into Date/from/to
    // 2) consturct the Date object for the appDate
    // 3) consturct the Date object for the startTime
    // 4) consturct the Date object for the endTime

    String[] appDetails = appString.split(",");

    if(appDetails.length == 2)
    {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            this.appDate = df.parse(appDetails[0]);
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy,mm:HH");
            String dFormat = appDetails[0] + "," + appDetails[1];
            this.startTime = formatter.parse(dFormat);
            dFormat = appDetails[0] + "," + appDetails[2];
            this.endTime = formatter.parse(dFormat);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.print("User Date is Invalid");
    }
}
public void setStartTime(Date startTime) 
{
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public Date getStartTime()
{
    return startTime;
}

public void setEndTime(Date endTime) 
{
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

public Date getEndTime()
{
    return endTime;
}

public void setAppdate(Date appDate) 
{
    this.appDate = appDate;
}

public Date getAppDate()
{
    return appDate;
}


public void add(Appointment a) 
{
    if (a.equals(a.getDate()))
    {
        if(a.getStartTime() < a.getEndTime())
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you not just use `Date` as it is? Why want you to compare an `Appointment` (containing start and end date) with a single `Date` object?

Comment: Use LocalDate (or LocalDateTIme) it's easier ;)=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Static block (almost)

Your code to exercise the class is in the wrong place. You have it stuck at the top of the class which is not syntactically correct. We *can* run code at the top, as a [static block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), but it needs to be labeled `static { … }`. A static block is not commonly used in my experience. And certainly is not the right place for what you are doing there.

## `main` method

Instead you should be using [a `main` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/). This non-[OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) little thingie is a trick, a hack, to solve the [chicken-or-the-egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) conundrum, to get us from no-app-running to our OOP idea of heaven with a bunch of objects floating around and passing messages to one another.

When first learning Java, do *not* try to understand all the syntax and purpose of the `main` method. Just accept it as a necessary evil to get the app running, it is merely the entrance point to execute the app. Focus on learning the OOP concepts and practices. Later, the `main` method and syntax will make more sense.

## Accessors

Here is a simplified re-write of your example code. We are just using a `LocalDate` for simplicity, just enough to show (a) a `main` method, and (b) getter/setter [accessor methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AppointmentDate {
    private LocalDate localDate;

    // Constructor
    public AppointmentDate ( LocalDate localDate ) {
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getLocalDate ( ) {
        return localDate;
    }

    public void setLocalDate ( LocalDate localDate ) {
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "AppointmentDate{ " +
                "localDate=" + localDate +
                " }";
    }

    // Not really a part of this class. A `main` method is just a hack to get our app launched.
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        String input = "23/01/2018";
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
        AppointmentDate ad = new AppointmentDate( ld );
        ad.setLocalDate( ld.plusWeeks( 1 ) );
        LocalDate newValue = ad.getLocalDate();
        System.out.println( newValue.toString() );  // Generate text representing the value of this `LocalDate` object in standard ISO 8601 format.

        List < AppointmentDate > list = new ArrayList <>( 3 );
        list.add( ad );
        list.add( new AppointmentDate( LocalDate.parse( "2018-02-13" ) ) );
        list.add( new AppointmentDate( LocalDate.parse( "2018-12-21" ) ) );
        System.out.println( list );
    }
}
```

> 2018-01-30
>
> [AppointmentDate{ localDate=2018-01-30 }, AppointmentDate{ localDate=2018-02-13 }, AppointmentDate{ localDate=2018-12-21 }]

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

## Appointments are tricky

While appointment tracking may seem intuitively simple, you are actually working on a very tricky subject.

The core problem is that politicians around the world are fond of redefining the time zone(s) under their jurisdiction. They do so quite frequently. They do so in both times of relative quiet and in times of turmoil.

The US and Canada have changed their offsets multiple times in recent decades. Turkey and Russia have changed their minds about going on or off DST multiple times in the last several years.

And politicians change their time zones with very little advance notice. And the notice seems to be growing shorter, despite the increased disturbance this causes in ever-more-computerized societies. Just last month, [Morocco announced](https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/2018/10/254474/morocco-standard-time-daylight-saving-time-gmt/) their country would stay on Daylight Saving Time (DST) permanent, cancelling on a Friday the DST cutover scheduled for that Sunday, leaving 0 business days warning — what a mess for IT staff. In May this year, [North Korea slipped their clock](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/may/05/time-for-change-north-korea-moves-clocks-forward-to-match-south) a half-hour to sync with South Korea, with apparently immediate effect (no advance notice at all).

These frequent and unpredictable changes mean we cannot responsibly track future appointments as moments, as specific points on the timeline. When we say something like “3 PM on January 23rd” we usually mean 3 PM *after* politicians may have made their changes to the clock.

So we must store future appointments as a date and a time-of-day without a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Then, when calculating a calendar we must dynamically apply the rules for the intended time zone as currently defined on that day. If we perform this dynamic-determination of a moment today, and again in three days, if the politicians have announced a change in the time zone definition, and if we have been able to update our [`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tz_database) data files in our operating systems, database engines, Java Virtual Machines, and various libraries, then we will **arrive at a different moment in time**.

## `LocalDateTime`

The `Local…` types in Java purposely lack any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So they cannot represent a moment. So we *never* use these to pinpoint actual events that happened in the past. But these types are what we need for future appointments.

The `LocalDateTime` class represents a date with a time-of-day without any zone/offset.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 ) ;  // 3 PM in 24-hour time.
LocalDateTime ldt= LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

When calculating a calendar, when we need a specific moment, we apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;  // Determine a moment, a specific point on the timeline.
```

## `Instant`

We can view that same moment in UTC by extracting a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;   // Adjust to UTC.
```

## `Duration`

Appointments are generally best stored as a starting point plus a duration. No need to store the stopping point as that can be calculated.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ;  // A one-hour appointment.
```

While we often want to adjust into a time zone for presentation to a user, generally behind-the-scenes it is best practice to track moments in UTC. So the starting and stopping points of an appointment calculated as moments should be done as a pair of `Instant` objects.

```
Instant start = ldt.atZone( z ).toInstant() ;
Instant stop = start.plus( d ) ;
```

## `Interval`

We can leverage a class to represent this pair of `Instant` objects, [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html).

This class is found in the *ThreeTen-Extra* library, a project led by the same man than led the Joda-Time, JSR 310, and *java.time* projects, Stephen Colebourne.

This class has very handy methods for comparison such as `abuts`, `overlaps`, `contains`, and so on. You will likely want to use these methods in a scheduling app.

## `Appointment.java`

Put this all together and we get a class like this:

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.threeten.extra.Interval;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Appointment {
    private LocalDateTime start;
    private Duration duration;

    // Constructor.
    public Appointment ( LocalDateTime start , Duration duration ) {
        this.start = start;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    // Might add some getter/setter methods in here.

    // Dynamically determine the start and stop points of this appointment, given today’s definition of the intended time zone.
    public Interval toInterval ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
        ZonedDateTime zdtStart = this.start.atZone( zoneId );
        Interval interval = Interval.of( zdtStart.toInstant() , this.duration );
        return interval;
    }

}
```

When you generate a `Interval` by calling your `toInterval` method, you may want the individual start and stop moments.

```
Instant start = interval.getStart() ;
Instant stop = interval.getEnd() ;
```

Those two `Instant` objects are in UTC by definition. If you want to see them through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId zAuckland = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = start.atZone( z ) ;  // Adjust from UTC to some time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = stop.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Future

You asked about checking to see if this appointment is in the future. Again, we need a time zone to properly answer than. The time zones around the world currently cover a range of about 26 to 27 hours. So within in that many hours of the current moment we cannot tell if a `LocalDateTime` is in the future or past without considering a time zone.

So let's add a method testing for the future that requires passing a time zone.

```
// Dynamically determine if this appointment will be in the future for some specific time zone.
public Boolean isFuture ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull( zoneId , "Must pass a time zone to determine if an appointment is in the future. Message # e1c64bc1-9a44-4d15-b20d-e68414fb5ab5.");
    ZonedDateTime zdtStart = this.start.atZone( zoneId );
    ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
    boolean isInTheFuture = zdtNow.isBefore( zdtStart );
    return isInTheFuture ;
}
```

## Start/Stop moments

Continuing the same theme on dynamically determining moments, let's add some methods to return the starting moment (inclusive) and stopping moment (exclusive). As discussed above, this requires passing a time zone.

The calling programmer could do this work herself. But I suspect this might be frequently needed enough to warrant adding these methods as a convenience.

```
// Get start moment for a particular time zone.
public ZonedDateTime toStartMoment ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
    ZonedDateTime zdt = this.toInterval( zoneId ).getStart().atZone( zoneId );
    return zdt;
}

// Get stop moment for a particular time zone.
public ZonedDateTime toStopMoment ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
    ZonedDateTime zdt = this.toInterval( zoneId ).getEnd().atZone( zoneId );
    return zdt;
}
```

Notice that I did not name these methods with the `get…`. Accessor methods, getters & setters, by convention imply accessing a simple property stored within the object. But here we are not storing the `ZonedDateTime` objects. These are dynamically-determined, so using a `get…` method could be misleading. Instead, I am trying to follow the [naming conventions laid down in the *java.time* project](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html).

## Immutable objects

Another lesson to learn from the *java.time* project is the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern.

Certain kinds of classes lend themselves to being read-only, created but not modified. The *java.time* classes certainly qualify. Whereas an invoice, for example, is expected to “mutate” (change), intuitively as a programmer I do not expect the date on the invoice to change unless I explicitly replace the date with a new object. So I want invoice to be a *mutable* object, but I want the `LocalDate` object stored on that invoice to be *immutable*.

I suspect our `Appointment` class might also be best designed an an immutable. So we have no `setter` methods involved. To effectively alter an appointment in your scheduling app, create a new `Appointment` object based on some of the values of the existing `Appointment` object. Notice in the *java.time* classes how this is done with various `with` methods, where the methods return a new object based on the original’s values but with some alteration.

## `Appointment.java` version 2

Let's put all that together into one example class.

And let's add a `main` method to exercise this class. First we create one appointment, and look at its dynamically-determined moments in UTC. Second, we collect some `Appointment` objects in a collection.

We have added a `toString` method override to report on the object’s state.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.threeten.extra.Interval;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

// An example class to show date-time handling for future appointments.
// Not necessarily ready for production use. Use at your own risk.
// Methods named according to the java.time naming conventions:
// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html
public class Appointment {
    private LocalDateTime start;
    private Duration duration;

    // Constructor.
    public Appointment ( LocalDateTime start , Duration duration ) {
        this.start = start;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    // Dynamically determine the start and stop points of this appointment, given today’s definition of the intended time zone.
    public Interval toInterval ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( zoneId , "Must pass a time zone to get the start/stop interval of an appointment. Message # bbf021e6-baa7-468d-83ad-cf73acb6702e." );
        ZonedDateTime zdtStart = this.start.atZone( zoneId );
        Interval interval = Interval.of( zdtStart.toInstant() , this.duration );
        return interval;
    }

    // Get start moment for a particular time zone.
    public ZonedDateTime toStartMoment ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = this.toInterval( zoneId ).getStart().atZone( zoneId );
        return zdt;
    }

    // Get stop moment for a particular time zone.
    public ZonedDateTime toStopMoment ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = this.toInterval( zoneId ).getEnd().atZone( zoneId );
        return zdt;
    }

    // Dynamically determine if this appointment will be in the future for some specific time zone.
    public Boolean isFuture ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( zoneId , "Must pass a time zone to determine if an appointment is in the future. Message # e1c64bc1-9a44-4d15-b20d-e68414fb5ab5." );
        ZonedDateTime zdtStart = this.start.atZone( zoneId );
        ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
        boolean isInTheFuture = zdtNow.isBefore( zdtStart );
        return isInTheFuture;
    }

    // -----------|  Object overrides  |---------------------------
    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "Appointment{ " +
                "start=" + start +
                " | duration=" + duration +
                " }";
    }

    // -----------|  main  |-------------
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        // See if a new appointment is in the future.
        Appointment a = new Appointment( LocalDateTime.of( 2018 , 12 , 25 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) , Duration.ofHours( 2 ) );  
        ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
        System.out.println( "For time zone: " + z + ", appointment interval is: " + a.toInterval( z ) );
        System.out.println( "Start: " + a.toStartMoment( z ) );
        System.out.println( "Stop: " + a.toStopMoment( z ) );

        Boolean isFuture = a.isFuture( z );
        System.out.println( a.toString() + " is future t/f: " + isFuture );

        // Collect some appointments.
        List < Appointment > list = new ArrayList <>( 3 );
        list.add( a );
        list.add( new Appointment( LocalDateTime.of( 2018 , 12 , 13 , 15 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) , Duration.ofMinutes( 90 ) ) );
        list.add( new Appointment( LocalDateTime.of( 2018 , 12 , 30 , 16 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) , Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ) );
        System.out.println( list );
    }

}
```

When run.

> For time zone: America/Montreal, appointment interval is: 2018-12-25T05:00:00Z/2018-12-25T07:00:00Z
>
> Start: 2018-12-25T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> Stop: 2018-12-25T02:00-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> Appointment{ start=2018-12-25T00:00 | duration=PT2H } is future t/f: true
>
> [Appointment{ start=2018-12-25T00:00 | duration=PT2H }, Appointment{ start=2018-12-13T15:00 | duration=PT1H30M }, Appointment{ start=2018-12-30T16:00 | duration=PT1H }]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, I clarified my thoughts there.